# How do you stop your xbox from doing the start up animation?

Tags: xbox-one

When ever I start up my Xbox One it does that animation where it shows the processor and then it explodes and the words xbox one are there. Then it just sits there for about a minute so I was wondering if there is a way to stop this from happening or to make my xbox start up faster.

Comment: Shows the processor? What do you mean? All I remember from turning my Xbox on is the Xbox One Splash Screen that appears when you boot the system.

Comment: Disclaimer: I dont own an xbox 1, however, if youve noticed that it has been taking longer over time, then you might want to consider cleaning the fans out (if its even possible to open the xbox up). If its consitently taken the same amount of time, like @MikeDurso said its just the normal startup process and you just need to be patient and let it do its thing.

Comment: Does it do this if you keep it on the sleep mode? This basically keeps it in a low power mode so that regular start ups are quicker. I haven't used my Xbox One X in about a year but I can test when I get home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what you are experiencing is the startup splash screen for the xbox one x.  It does the animation you mention and then continues and should do the normal xbox logo animation.  While this animation is going on it is doing all of the startup processes the xbox needs to get done so there isn't any way to get around that.